# API Gateway CreateAuthorizer fails with InternalFailure

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation

When I try to create custom authorizerer for my AWS API Gateway using CloudFormation, it freezes trying all the time to execute `CreateAuthorizer` call, but fails. Here is the minimum CloudFormation template with which I can reproduce that behavior:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Resources:
    ApiGatewayV1:
        Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi"
        Properties:
            Name: "test"

    ApiAuthorizerV1:
        Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Authorizer"
        Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref "ApiGatewayV1"
            Name: "test"
            Type: "TOKEN"
            AuthorizerUri: !Sub "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda::${AWS::AccountId}:function:${!stageVariables.AuthorizerLambdaName}/invocations"
            IdentitySource: "method.request.header.Authorization"
            AuthorizerResultTtlInSeconds: 3600
```

**CloudTrail** log:

```
"errorCode": "InternalFailure",
"errorMessage": "An unknown error occurred",
"requestParameters": {
    "restApiId": "lweme6j3wk",
    "createAuthorizerInput": {
        "providerARNs": [],
        "identitySource": "method.request.header.Authorization",
        "authorizerResultTtlInSeconds": 3600,
        "type": "TOKEN",
        "name": "test",
        "authorizerUri": "arn:aws:apigateway:eu-central-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda::<ACCOUNT_ID>:function:${stageVariables.AuthorizerLambdaName}/invocations"
    },
    "template": false
},
"responseElements": null,
"requestID": "470e2efa-d3c1-11e7-b0cc-b7fd2383ef6b",
"eventID": "2ceccaa5-9b97-4b1e-93e5-3c4e6bca419d",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, that was supper bizzare. When I explicitely specified region in the target lambda ARN it worked!

Replaced:

```
arn:aws:lambda::<ACCOUNT_ID>
```

With:

```
arn:aws:lambda:<REGION>:<ACCOUNT_ID>
```

(and yes, it works with `${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}` placeholder, I used fixed values to check.